# "him answering questions" or "his answering questions"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which is correct: "they agree to him answering questions" or "they agree to his answering questions" ?

Comment: Either is fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, both are totally fine, it just depends on the register (and to some extent, the meaning).

In your example, 'answering' is a gerund, meaning that is it a verb functioning as a noun in the sentence, hence the use of the ING form. Therefore, strictly grammatically speaking, it should be preceded by a possessive determiner and not a possessive pronoun.

However, it is quite in use today, using the possessive pronoun instead of the possessive determiner.

There seems to be a difference in meaning: PERS PRO (HIM in your example)+ V-ING would tend to focus on the person doing the action (namely "answering questions", HIM nor HER) whereas PERS DET + V-ING would on the other hand focus on the process of the action (ANSWERING questions, not swimming or eating Bertie Bott's beans).

Hope this is useful.